# Лицензирование и защита PHP скрипта

Tags: скрипт, лицензирование, php

Здравствуйте

Недавно написал PHP скрипт для помощи в SEO. 
Хочу его за символическую цену продавать. 
Но так же не хочу чтобы он был в свободном доступе, а работал только с выданной лицензией.

1. Лицензия привязанная к домену.
2. Время играет роль, где то год будет действовать лицензия.

Как это можно реализовать?
Спасибо

Comment: [IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/), но это не для «символической» цены.

Comment: @sergiks защита хорошая, но наслышан, что китайцы за 10 баксов файл приводят в читаемый вид.

Comment: php штука не компилируемая потому 100% защиты не будет.. выдавайте купившему кей и чекайте его курлом например или в привязке к домену ище.. но опять же при необзодимости все это легко правится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адекватная защита вряд ли может быть универсальна. Скорее, заточена под конкретный продукт, встроена в его структуру, завязана на многие классы-функции.

Ваш скрипт помогает в SEO? Может, сделать так, что без правильной лицензии скрипт работает, но фиговенько - что-то делает, но SEO рейтинг не особо улучшает.

Не раскрыты вопросы:

1. к чему хотите привязывать лицензию? К хосту, к ip, к конкретному железу сервера?
2. время играет роль? Лицензия вечная, или смотрит на часы?

**Общие рекомендации:**

Используйте обфускацию кода, чтобы его сложно было понять человеку. Используйте похожесть символов '`0`' и '`O`', '`1`' и '`l`' в названиях функций и классов.

Закрывайте фрагменты кода в [`eval()`](http://www.php.net//manual/ru/function.eval.php) и кодируйте в `base64`.

Допишите часть вашего кода в известный открытый компонент — маловероятно, что станут пересматривать весь код, скажем, в `vendors/`[`monolog`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), если у вас используется [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) и несколько сторонних компонентов.

Этих ухищрений должно быть достаточно для умеренной защиты от просто-халявщиков.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. 1. Лицензия привязанная к домену. 2. Время играет роль, где то год будет действовать лицензия.

Answer (score 2):

Есть скрипты которые генерируют класс защиты, после обфускации можно подключать к себе в скрипт.
phpMyLicense примерно $25 на codecanyon лежит.
Функционал неплохой. Я на его примере писала свой кабинет лицензий.

Answer (score 1):

Есть инструмент специально для этого:

### **PCP-CS — PHP Code Protect Client-Server**.

Другими словами клиент-серверное приложение для привязки скриптов к определенным ограничениям (домен, ip сервера и т.д.).
Ключевые преимущества:

1. *Лёгкая интеграция* в нужный скрипт. Достаточно вставить код клиента в
   скрипт и прописать необходимые параметры
2. *Встроенная админка* для управления серверной частью. Просмотр логов, управление лицензиями и пр
3. Интересная реализация проверок. Проверки лицензии осуществляются сначала из локального ключа, и если период проверки истёк - данные запрашиваются с сервера проверки
4. Ограничение срока действия ключа
   и др.

PCP-CS на русском http://pafnuty.name/statyi/157-pcp-cs.html

Answer (score 0):

Ну в плане защиты самого кода, то можно использовать фускацию кода,а вообще есть куча софтин которые делают все что надо. Лицензия, я думаю за этим вам надо обратится либо к юристу либо в торгово промышленную палату в вашем городе/регионе.